# phpinfo() showing source with php 5.6 with apache 2.4. Possible configuration issue

Tags: php, apache, configuration, apache2.4, php-5.6

I'm trying to configure php 5.6 with apache 2.4. I installed php5.6 and apache2.4 using brew on a mac (yosemite).

But when I go to view my test.php page that only has

`<?
phpfinfo()
?>`

it's just displaying the php source. Even though I've Loaded the php5 module in apache

`LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.9/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

I have restarted apache after making the changes above.

Any suggestions would be grateful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add PHP handler into apache configuration.
Currently your Apache does not know how to handle .php files, and passes then as text :)

Comment: Sorry I already had this in. I'll update with how I fixed it.